# Unable to launch UWP Application using .Net Memory Profiler

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, uwp, memory-profiling

I want to see my **UWP** Application performance and **Memory Leakage** using **.Net Memory Profiler**. When I am trying to launch my application I am getting below error.

[image]

May I know how to run my application using **.Net Memory Profiler**.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer to why .NET memory profiler does not work with UWP, but here is an alternative.

Visual Studio 2015 and above come in-built with visual diagnostic tools that let you quickly identify memory and performance related issues. Take a look at [Tools for profiling and performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/tools-for-profiling-and-performance)